# How to delete row based off of matched cell in a different workbook?

Tags: excel, vba

I have two different workbooks, workbook A and workbook B. I am filtering workbook A based off of some criteria, and from whatever is left after filtering, I am taking the values in column D from Sheet 1 of that workbook and looking for matches in column E from Sheet 2 of workbook B. Workbook B is the active workbook in this case.

If there is a match (if the value in column D of workbook A after filtering can be found in column E of workbook B), I want to delete the entire row where that match was found from workbook B. However, I'm running into some difficulty in performing this. Here is what I have so far:

```
Sub UpdateMatrix()
'
' UpdateMatrix Macro
'

'
Dim Cell As Range
Dim FoundCell As Range
Dim FindString As String
' Dim RowNum As Long

For Each Cell In Workbooks("Workbook A.xlsm").Worksheets("Sheet 1").Range("D6:D65536")

    If IsEmpty(Cell) Then Exit For
    If Cell.EntireRow.Hidden = False Then
        With Workbooks("Workbook B.xlsm").Worksheets("Sheet 2").Range("E2:E65536")
            Set FoundCell = .Find(What:=Cell.Value, _
                                  LookIn:=xlValues, _
                                  LookAt:=xlWhole, _
                                  SearchOrder:=xlByRows, _
                                  SearchDirection:=xlNext, _
                                  MatchCase:=False)
            If Not FoundCell Is Nothing Then
                FoundCell.EntireRow.Delete
            End If
        End With
    End If
Next

End Sub
```

However, it's not working as intended (even though there is a match between the workbooks, the row is not being deleted from workbook B). Any thoughts? Thanks so much!

Comment: Try `FoundCell.EntireRow.Delete`. Also, check if something was found before you attempt to delete a row (i.e. `If Not FoundCell Is Nothing Then`)

Comment: Also add a workbook reference here `With Sheets("Sheet 2").Range("E:E")`.

Comment: Hmm I tried both suggestions and it still doesn't seem to work.

Comment: we will need a bit more than: it still doesn't work. Is it throwing an error? code runs but nothing happens? Screen print of the error will help as well. Can you update your code with the changes you've made?

Comment: I updated the code with the changes I've made. No error is thrown- it's just not deleting the row as intended.

Comment: put a debug.print statement after ```If Not FoundCell Is Nothing Then``` and see if it is finding anything

Comment: Never mind I realized that I was starting my range at the top of the column when values only started to appear later down, so it was exiting the for loop and ending the macro. Thanks so much for all your help!